# while loop hang forever during TCP/IP communication for Client Side?

Tags: c#, .net, server, client, tcp

I am creating very simple TCP/IP communication program between Client and Server. Aim is just to exchange some string between them.

The Client Server side needs to send and receive some simple string to Server.

The problem is that it works perfectly when I send data to Sever using StreamWriter. However, when I enable the StreamReader, the while loop just hanging forever. The "Console.Write("> ");" line is only executed once at the beginning but never prompted again in the second time.

Here is the code below.

Note "_client" is already connected socket for TcpClient declared as TcpClient _client in the another part of code.

```
            _sReader = new StreamReader(_client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
            _sWriter = new StreamWriter(_client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            _isConnected = true;
            String sData = null;

            while (_isConnected)
            {
                Console.Write("&gt; ");
                sData = Console.ReadLine();

                _sWriter.WriteLine(sData);
                _sWriter.Flush();


                //If I commnet out these two lines of code below, then there is no problem. Program works fine.
                String sDataIncomming = _sReader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(sDataIncomming);

                //While loop just hanging after this line. 
                //It does not even break the while loop.
                //Either while loop goes back to the top of the line.
                //Just stuck here. Why ? 

            }
```

If I comment out the two lines of code for StreamReader, the program works perfect again.

How can I fix this problem ? Sharing your knowledge will be really appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a partial answer to this problem.

I think if the socket does not  receive anything from Server, it seems that this code line stuck forever.

```
String sDataIncomming = _sReader.ReadLine();
```

So new question is that how can I check if some string is coming from server or not ?

If no string is coming from server, then just stop listening from the socket.